# How do you return a default value if a LINQ to entities query returns no values

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, defaultifempty

In a LINQ to entities expression like this:

```
var vote = (from vote in db.Vote where
    vote.Voter.Id == user.Id
    select v).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do you add a DefaultIfEmpty value so that when there's no vote I'd get a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going for a very simple approach which was recommended by an answer here that was latter erased:

```
var vote = (from vote in db.Vote 
            where vote.Voter.Id == user.Id
            select v).FirstOrDefault();
if (vote == null) {
    vote = new Vote() { .... };
    db.AddToVoteSet(vote);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this did not satisfy your original question. You explicitly asked for it to return a default value, not to create a new value if it didn't already exist. (This is fine code, just doesn't do what you asked.)

Answer (score 20):

Another approach, if `Vote` is a reference type and thus uses null as its default value, would be to use the null coalescing operator:

```
var vote = (db.Vote
   .Where(v => v.Voter.Id == user.Id)
   .FirstOrDefault()) ?? defaultVote;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add your own extension method. For instance:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T defaultValue)
    { 
        return sequence.Any() ? sequence.First() : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

With that class in scope, you can say:

```
var vote = (from vote in db.Vote where
    vote.Voter.Id == user.Id
    select v).FirstOrDefault(yourDefaultValue);
```

Of course, your method can also have an overload that returns default(T), if that was what you where looking for. There is already defined a DefaultIfEmpty extension method in the built-in Extension class, so I named the method in the example "FirstOrDefault", which seems like a better fit.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() already exists as an extension method :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx

Comment: Why should I re-write a FirstOrDefault when there's already one designed for that purpose?

Comment: Did you not want to be able to select another value than default ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: No, I just want to use the preovided methods, not re-implement them.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the default value before getting the first element.

```
var vote = db.Vote
    .Where(v => v.Voter.Id == user.Id)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultVote)
    .First();
```

Note that you can now safely use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`.

**UPDATE**

LINQ to Entity does not recognize the `DefaultIfEmpty()` extension method. But you can just use the null coalescing operator.

```
var vote = db.Vote.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Voter.Id == user.Id) ?? defaultVote;
```

Comment: If when adding a default you can use First, why does FirstOrDefault exists at all?

Comment: Many of the LINQ operators are somewhat redundant - sequence.Any() can be rewritten as sequence.Count() > 0. You can use sequence.Where(item => Condition(item)).First() or sequence.First(item => Condition(item)). You can use joins or nested queries. When writing code you can use for, do, and while loops. You can even use goto. Usually there is not just one way to achieve a given goal.

Comment: Note that seq.Count() (for objects that don't implement ICollection) will enumerate the full sequence while seq.Any() will return as soon as an element is found. Similar, but different. :)

Comment: Of course, the count solution might be much slower. I just wanted to point out that there are usually quite a few ways to achieve a goal.

Comment: `First()` will throw an exception if the sequence is empty. `FirstOrDefault()` will not, so you can control the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if I turn the resultset into a List, the Defaultifempty() works  I don't know if I've inadvertantly crossed over into Linq area.

```
var results = (from u in rv.tbl_user
                        .Include("tbl_pics")
                        .Include("tbl_area")
                        .Include("tbl_province")
                        .ToList()
                        where u.tbl_province.idtbl_Province == prov
                       select new { u.firstName, u.cellNumber, u.tbl_area.Area, u.ID, u.tbl_province.Province_desc,
                                    pic = (from p3 in u.tbl_pics
                                           where p3.tbl_user.ID == u.ID
                                           select p3.pic_path).DefaultIfEmpty("defaultpic.jpg").First()
                                               }).ToList();
```